# HTML simple list sorting

Tags: javascript, html

is there is simple way to sort only the outer level of multilist level in HTML?
(it's not important to sort the inner level of the lists)
If possible just javascript code, no jQuery since i never used it.

Example: Before sorting

1. List Z

   - Katty
   - Della
2. List G

   - Test
   - fox
3. List R

   - ABC
   - AAC

After sorting:

1. List G

   - Test
   - fox
2. List R

   - ABC
   - AAC
3. List Z

   - Katty
   - Della

Thank you in advance
Mike

After using the Jquery method answered below, i got error "Object does not support this property or method??

Update: here is acode sample:

```
<head>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="./js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">



    function sortDesc()
    {
        $('ul.list > li').sortElements(function(a, b){
        return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;});
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="main">
            <div class="c1">
                <div id="example-list">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="middle"     align="center" title='sort' style="cursor:pointer" valign="middle" align="center"  style="width:20px; height:20px;">
                                <img border="0" src="./js/r_oinfo.gif" width="20" height="20"  onclick="sortDesc()">
                        </td>
                    </table>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li>
                            Search

                        </li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                se 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                se 2
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                se 0
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <li>
                            Sort
                        </li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                so 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                so 0
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <li>
                            Filter

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML code. p.s jQuery would be very useful for this.

Comment: Is this list generated dynamically.

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a good opportunity to start learning about jQuery; it has a lot to offer when it comes to [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) operations.

There's a nice write-up of element sorting using jQuery at http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/.

Using the `sortElements` approach outlined above, the following should allow you to sort your list (assuming that the top-level `ul` has a class of `toplevellist`).

```
$('ul.toplevellist > li').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

There's a complete example at http://qd9.co.uk/projects/jQuery-Plugins/sort/demo.html. To use this on your site you need to:

1) Add a jQuery script reference to your web page (e.g. `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`)

2) Save the file [jquery.sort.js](http://qd9.co.uk/projects/jQuery-Plugins/sort/jquery.sort.js) from the example and copy it to your server, and add it to your web page as a script reference.

3) Add a call to the `sortElements` function in the example.

If you definitely do not want to use jQuery, then the approach outlined at that page can still be used, depending on your level of JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: Just FYI, the link you pointed to is not very jQuery. Sure, it uses `$.fn.func`, but the function can be copied and used as plain JS.

Comment: I have error message if i run this code
I iwll post the full code

Comment: will can you please give me a simple javascript code?
as i said, i can't get jquery to work, i have a very complex page JSP
normally i'm a server side developer however, i have to correct an urgent bug, therefore i cannot just start learn jQury at the moment

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details, which should help you get this working.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your support however, it doesn't work.
I followed the steps, what happend is the following
it works well with single level list.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your support however, it doesn't work.
I followed the steps, what happend is the following
it works well with single level list. when i try to use it with multi level list it sorts all levels and it mix top level and inner level

Comment: Thank you Richard! it works fine now, the problem was that i used the html element in incorrect way. after i included the <UL> tag inside the <li> tags it works fine. thanks again